# PowerShell script to find the user password expiry date and renew it to a custom date

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, office365

I want to find a PowerShell script to find the user password expiry date and time and renew it to customized time for bulk users.

I tried it with with the below code:

```
Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName 'xxx@abc.com' | select *password* |fl
```

This can fetch only last password change but not when the password will expire.

Answer (score 1):

There is no field you can query for this task. You have to do this in two steps.

1. Get the password policy

   ```
   $PasswordPolicy = Get-MsolPasswordPolicy
   ```
2. Calculate the time to the next password expiry date with some math magic

   ```
   $(Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName  "SuperUser").LastPasswordChangeTimestamp.AddDays($PasswordPolicy.ValidityPeriod)
   ```

More details can be found here [Office 365 – Retrieve User Password Expiration Date](https://audministrator.wordpress.com/2018/12/04/office-365-retrieve-user-password-expiration-date/)

Comment: Thanks ! but could you help me with below scenario. for e.g. 
i want to set the user password expiry to next one year which is about to be expired in a week

How to extend his expiry date ?

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible. In this case you can create a separate password policy and apply the policy to this user. If you want you can disable the password expiration completely for this user.